# Unable to upload file from $_FILES array in drupal7

Tags: file, upload, drupal-7

I am trying to upload file from `$_FILES` array. but getting following error in drupal7.

```
The specified file temporary://fileOYnPHK could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured.
This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log.
```

The `sites/default/files` has permissions `777`

Here is my code

```
if($_FILES['files']['name']['field_tenant_review_ref_und_form_field_tenancy_document_und_0']){
    $file_path = file_save_data(file_get_contents($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']['field_tenant_review_ref_und_form_field_tenancy_document_und_0']),
    'public://sites/default/files/'.$_FILES['files']['name']['field_tenant_review_ref_und_form_field_tenancy_document_und_0']);
   }
   //$tenant_review->field_tenancy_document->file->set($file_path);
```

Is there any mistake in code? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'public://sites/default/files/'
```

should probably be changed to

```
'public://'
```

because it probaby already contains the `sites/default/files` path, if that path is set in Drupal settings as the public files path.

Edit:
The permissions for the files folder shoud be set as most permissive to 775 for security reasons.